# AWS: No address associated with hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

Create an EC2 instance and file system. I am trying to mount the file system, for which I use the following command:

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 fs-0d06d36f390aeXXXX.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:/myDir
```

And I am getting this error:

```
mount.nfs4: Failed to resolve server fs-0d06d36f390aeXXXX.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com: No address associated with hostname
```

Could someone guide me to solve this?

Comment: From where do you run the command line?

Comment: @YLR Inside the EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the similar issue by following the instructions in [this article](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/efs-mount-issue-failed-to-resolve-server-name-or-service-not-known/).

To sum up you need to go to your VPC configuration and make sure that: "DNS hostnames" and "DNS resolution" are both enabled.

After changing those settings I had to restart my machine and it connected.

You can try running the commands below instead of a restart:

```
service rpcbind restart
service nfs restart
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this issue by using following command.

first you need to nslookup nfsdomain from working machine and take the IP address

```
nslookup fs-7dsqsssscas5e11sefs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Server:         127.0.0.51
Address:        127.0.0.51#51

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   fs-7dsqsssscas5e11sefs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.143.27.147
```

Add the IP address into /etc/hosts with nfsdoamin

```
vi /etc/hosts

10.143.27.147 fs-7dsqsssscas5e11sefs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

and try to mount with following command

`sudo mount -t nfs4 fs-7dsqsssscas5e11sefs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt`